# Bootstrap tooltip not working with jquery.slim when importing via webpack

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, webpack, bootstrap-4

I installed via npm bootstrap 4.6.0 and jquery 3.6.0.

This code is working:

```js
import jQuery from "jquery/dist/jquery";
import "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap";
    
(function ($) {
    "use strict";   
    $("[data-toggle='tooltip']").tooltip()
})(jQuery);
```

This code instead is not working, with error `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function`

Notice that the only difference is that jquery slim is used in place of jquery.

```js
import jQuery from "jquery/dist/jquery.slim";
import "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap";
    
(function ($) {
    "use strict";   
    $("[data-toggle='tooltip']").tooltip()
})(jQuery);
```

Other bootstrap functionalities (e.g. collapse) work even with slim.

It looks like for some reason bootstrap fails to load some functions, like tooltip (also tried with scrollspy, same problem)

I also tried to `console.log($.fn)` and actually with jquery slim I can't find a bunch of functions...

Comment: Do you have `popper.js` installed. I'm pretty sure tooltips only work with `popper.js`. (make sure it is above `bootstrap.min.js`)

Comment: Do you have by chance previous configured the ProvidePlugin (WebPack) for jquery? Configure this for slim.

Comment: @Gunnarhawk I installed popper.js and I assume that it's included by bootstrap components (otherwise, the first code example wouldn't work)

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt my point is exactly to avoid ProvidePlugin. I need to get jquery in some files and jquery slim in other files

Comment: You can avoid it, but must live with the fact, that broken modules (like jquery plugins) will not work. `$(...).tooltip `

Answer (score 0):

According to the official documentation [Tooltips Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/tooltips/):

> Tooltips rely on the 3rd party library Popper.js for positioning. You must include popper.min.js before bootstrap.js or use bootstrap.bundle.min.js / bootstrap.bundle.js which contains Popper.js in order for tooltips to work!

So you need to install it between your jQuery and Bootstrap.
Or you can just install bootstrap.bundle.min.js and bootstrap.bundle.js which already contains Popper.js.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap's tooltip functionality relies on the full version of jQuery, and it is not included in the slim version of jQuery. The slim version of jQuery is a smaller version that excludes some of the less commonly used features, including some jQuery plugins that Bootstrap relies on.

To use Bootstrap's tooltip functionality with the slim version of jQuery, you can include the tooltip plugin separately. You can do this by adding the following line to your code after importing the bootstrap module:

```
import "bootstrap/js/dist/tooltip";
```

This will import the tooltip plugin separately and make it available for use with the slim version of jQuery.

Here's an example of how you can modify your code to use the slim version of jQuery with the Bootstrap tooltip plugin:

```
import jQuery from "jquery/dist/jquery.slim";
import "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap";
import "bootstrap/js/dist/tooltip"; // add this line
    
(function ($) {
    "use strict";   
    $("[data-toggle='tooltip']").tooltip()
})(jQuery);
```